# I have a two data frames df and df1 have same id columns but different column names in both data frames and I want update values in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]
[image]

I want to update df1 as per updated df1 , if df1 have nans replace with values if df have values matched with ID column on both data frames.

### My Expected Output is in the second image nan replaces with values
I have provided sample below

ID    QD   QP   QE

101   4    6    4

102   5    8    5

103   7    6    6

104   8    3    5

105   4    2    5

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ID` columns is sorted and these two columns are one-to-one correspondence, you can use

```py
df1[df1.isnull()] = df.values
```

```
print(df1)

    ID   QD   QP   QE
0  101  4.0  6.0  4.0
1  102  5.0  8.0  5.0
2  103  7.0  6.0  6.0
3  104  8.0  3.0  5.0
4  105  4.0  2.0  5.0
```

If not, you'd better set the `ID` column as index and choose one among `fillna` method, `combine_first` method and `update` method to update column according to index.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')

# fillna
df1 = df1.fillna(df.set_index('ID').set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)).reset_index()

# combine_first, if df is bigger than your original df1,
# the additional rows and columns are added
df1 = df1.combine_first(df.set_index('ID').set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)).reset_index()

# update method will modify data inplace,
# you need to do reset index in separate step
df1.update(df.set_index('ID').set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1))
df1.reset_index()
```

```
print(df1)


    ID   QD   QP   QE
0  101  4.0  6.0  4.0
1  102  5.0  8.0  5.0
2  103  7.0  6.0  6.0
3  104  8.0  3.0  5.0
4  105  4.0  2.0  5.0
```

Comment: if my index have duplicates on both dfs how to do update function.

Comment: @harishm Do you mean `ID` column in `df` have same value and their corresponding `CO2`, `CO4` and `CR6` are different?